# how to set dropdown box invisible in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

how to set drop down as invisible when page loading in codeigniter.i want to show that drop down later. This is my code for drop down load from database results..how do i set visibility :none or invisisible this drop down

```
foreach ($sources as $row) {
          $options3[$row->id] = $row->source;
        }

 echo '<td>'.form_dropdown('source_id', $options3, $this->input->post('source_id'), "id='source_id'");
```

Comment: Fourth paramater is for applying custom html to drop down field. Like you can add "style='visiblity:hidden'".

Answer (score 0):

Just add any attribute you need as a string in the fourth parameter of `form_dropdown()`

```
form_dropdown('source_id', $options3, $this->input->post('source_id'), "id='source_id'");
```

becomes

```
form_dropdown('source_id', $options3, $this->input->post('source_id'), "id='source_id' style='display:none;'");
```

Answer (score 0):

echo
''.form_dropdown
('source_id',
$options3, $this->input-

> post('source_id'),
>   "id='source_id' style='display:none;' "); #pass the style in the fourth parameter to hide the combo